# FC command line to compare certain files only in the folders

Tags: batch-file, command

I wish to know how am I able to use batch scripting to use FC command to compare certain files in the folder. I had the whitelisting done. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give a file comparison between the config.sys and the autoexec.bat in the current directory:

```
fc c:\autoexec.bat c:\config.sys
```

and if you want to compare in in binary format:

```
fc c:\autoexec.bat c:\config.sys /b
```

[More details is here...](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 fc /b folder1\*.cfg folder2\*.cfg
```

Comment: [fc | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc) Option /b:`Compares the two files in binary mode, byte by byte, and does not attempt to resynchronize the files after finding a mismatch. This is the default mode for comparing files that have the following file extensions: .exe, .com, .sys, .obj, .lib, or .bin.`